# Reveal a <div> containing a database object only when another <div> containing a database object from the same row is clicked - Django

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-templates, django-views

I am developing a website for a mobile barber service. There's a page on the website which displays all the barbers on the service. Each barber has a hidden 'div' containing their booking calendar, this appears when they click on a barber (using JavaScript). The booking calendar is a 3rd party booking system, and I input the barber's specific calendar url into the model form and then display it in the template like so:

```
<iframe class="booking-system" src="{{BarberProfile.booking_link}}" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My problem is, when a barber is clicked, it displays all the 'divs' containing all of the barbers booking calendars. How can I only show the booking calendar of the barber that is clicked, and hide all of the other barber's booking calendars that are not clicked?

An example of the page, and the 'div' containing the booking calendar:

[image: example of booking div]

I am very new to web development but have a pretty solid understanding of HTML & CSS, but a weak understanding of JavaScript so please be very clear in your suggestions. I am unsure if the solution to this will lie in Django views, JavaScript, or CSS.

My current code (I have edited out some which is irrelevant to this question):

views.py

```
def barbers_view(request):

    queryset_list = BarberProfile.objects.all()

    context = {
        "queryset_list": queryset_list,
    }

    return render (request, "barbers.html", context)
```

barbers.html

```
<div class="viewport_content">

        {% for BarberProfile in queryset_list %}

        <div class="booking-div">
            <iframe class="booking-system" src="{{BarberProfile.booking_link}}" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>

        <a class="content_box">
            <div class="image_box" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image.url}})">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4 class="barber_name"> {{BarberProfile.first_name}} </h4>
                <p class="barber_bio"> {{BarberProfile.bio}} </p>
            </div>    
        </a>

        {% endfor %}

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/booking.js" %}"></script>
```

barbers.css

```
.viewport_content{
    display: grid;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 75px);
    padding: 75 9.375 0 9.375;
}

    .content_box{
        margin: 0 9.375 18.75 9.375;
    }

        .image_box{
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .barber_name{
            line-height: 13.125px;
            margin: 18.75 0 0 0;
            font-size: 17.5px;
            text-transform: lowercase;
        }

        .barber_bio{
            line-height: 23.75px;
            margin: 12.5 0 12.5 0;
            color: #3F3F3F;
        }

    .booking-div{
        position: fixed;
        height: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        right: 0px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
        .booking-div.open{
            height: 100%;
        }
            .booking-system{
                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 37.5px);
                margin: -15 0 -4.25 18.75; /*bottom margin not responding*/
                padding: 0;
                background-color: white;
                border: 0px;
            }

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px){
    .viewport_content{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .booking-div{
        width: 87.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px){
    .viewport_content{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .booking-div{
        width: 500px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    .viewport_content{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .booking-div{
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

booking.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".content_box").on("click", function(){

        $(".booking-div").toggleClass("open");

    })

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your js code under script tag and then do like this

```
<div class="viewport_content">

        {% for BarberProfile in queryset_list %}

        <div class="booking-div" id="{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking">
            <iframe class="booking-system" src="{{BarberProfile.booking_link}}" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>

        <a class="content_box" id="{{BarberProfile.id}}" onClick="toggle_content(this.id)">
            <div class="image_box" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image.url}})">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4 class="barber_name"> {{BarberProfile.first_name}} </h4>
                <p class="barber_bio"> {{BarberProfile.bio}} </p>
            </div>    
        </a>

        {% endfor %}

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    function toggle_content(clicked_id){ 
        $('#'+clicked_id+'-booking').toggle(); 
      } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sumeet, how would I style #{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking in CSS. I need to give #{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking.open a height of 100% to show it. Currently, #{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking.open{ height:100% } doesn't work.

Comment: you can use class for that. well django tags `{{}}` can not be passed to css or javascript directly. easiest way for your problem is to add css to class `.booking-div{height:100%}`

Comment: But then I would need to change the JavaScript to something like: `$("#{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking").toggleClass("booking-div.open");` Is that correct, and if so what is the correct code?

Comment: so you want to add `height:100%` only when that div is open, right ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The div is hidden until a barber is clicked.

Comment: `.booking-div.open{height:100%}` is fine in css, you don't need to toggel it. try the code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Just tried it now and then hidden 'div' (.booking-div) won't show. The problem is that $("#{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking").toggleClass("open"); toggles #{{BarberProfile.id}}-booking to .open, not .booking-div which contains the height 100%. For example, in my style sheet: `.booking-div{ height: 0px } .booking-div.open{ height: 100% }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163870/discussion-between-sumeet-kumar-and-will-dpard).